# Errors thrown when trying to run basic.sh in sosumi

Tags: qemu, hackintosh

I was hoping that you could help me. I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while.
When I try to start up the clover boot loader or run the basic.sh file, I get these errors in the terminal:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.1 [bit 19]

qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.2 [bit 20]

qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.movbe [bit 22]

qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.aes [bit 25]

qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.xsave [bit 26]

qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.avx [bit 28]

qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.bmi1 [bit 3]

qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.avx2 [bit 5]
```

etc.

I have no idea what they mean. Could you please tell me a solution? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling manually. It didn't work and it threw these errors at me again. I followed the instructions in the readme: https://github.com/foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM

Qemu and everything it needs, all the dependencies are installed on my computer.

When I run the clover bootloader, it just shows a bunch of text then brings me back to the menu. I hit enter again. last time i kept ending up in the shell, and I don't know why.

Why does it keep crashing? Could you tell me pls how to fix it?

This is the second time I'm struggling with this, please help.

UPDATE: I tried using this repo: https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM and got the same errors. It's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The shell script you're running starts QEMU asking it to provide a guest CPU with various features (including SSE4, AVX and AVX2). With KVM, the only way we can give the guest a CPU with a feature like AVX is if the host CPU has it, because we run guest code directly on the host CPU. QEMU is warning you that you asked for something it can't do, because the host CPU you're running it on doesn't have those features. QEMU removes the features it can't provide from the set of things it tells the guest about via the CPUID registers.

If the guest OS really needs a CPU with AVX2 and all the rest of it, you need to run on a newer host CPU.

If the guest OS is happy to read the CPUID registers and adjust itself to avoid using features that aren't there, then you could adjust the -cpu options the script is passing to make it request something with fewer features, but all this will do is mean that QEMU won't print the warnings -- it won't change how the guest runs on that kind of CPU.

Comment: So, you're basically telling me that my CPU can't support it, right? That's what I understood-- That and the fact that the script appears to be asking for more hardware than I have.